# Is the following satetment is true or false?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Is the following statement is true ?

There exist polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, with complex coefficients, such that$ \left(\frac{f(x)} {g(x)}\right)^ 2$ =$ x$.

i thinks  it is true because $\frac{f(x)} {g(x)}$ =$x^{1/2}$ which contain  both + and -  that is every complex number is real number  so this  satetment is true

Comment: Just look at lead terms.  If $f(x)=f_nx^n+\cdots, g(x)=g_mx^m+\cdots $ then, writing $\left( f(x) \right)^2=x\left( g(x) \right)^2$ we see that the lead term on the left has even degree ( $2n$) but the lead term on the right has odd degree ( $2m+1$).

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning.  Clearly $x^{1/2}$ is not a rational function.  You may be interested in proving this from either an algebraic or an analytic perspective.

Comment: @lulu But if we take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)$ =$ x^{1/2}$ then it will be trues,,,??  pliz tell me

Comment: You asked for polynomials.

Comment: yes  my example is a  polynomial

Comment: No, it isn't.  In your example, $f(x)=x$ is a polynomial but $g(x)=x^{1/2}$ is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is false. If it was true, you would have $(f(x))^2=x(g(x))^2$. But the first polynomial has even degree, whereas the second one has odd degree.

Comment: carlos santosBut if we take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)$ =$ x^{1/2}$ then it will be trues,,,??  pliz tell me

Comment: @Michael $x^{1/2}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: it continious as,, polynomail is continous

Comment: @Michael I don't know what is it that you mean by that.

Comment: i mean g(x) = $x^{1/2}$  is polynomial  and also it is conitinious

Comment: @Michael I don't why you keep saying that it is continuous. The original question did not mention continuity. And a polynomial is an expression of the type $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$. Therefore $x^{1/2}$ is **not** a polynomial.

Comment: thanks a lots @ jose carlos santos